# How Show progress bar while loading webview load url in android

Tags: android, webview, loading

I'm new for android app....

When using webview to show html pages,

there will be several seconds of blank page before it finished rendering.

For better user experience, is there a way to make it show a loading image during that several seconds?

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gds.grocerydoorstep;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.gds.grocerydoorstep.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create a custom WebViewClient and overrider onPageStarted and onPageFinished.

Here's example code:

```
public class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
...
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    //TODO: show progress bar here
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //TODO: hide progress bar here
}
...
}
```

Don't forget to set custom WebViewClient:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```